# jQuery/jQueryUI conflict with mockup wireframe js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using mockup wirfame with drag and drop system and there jquery files are conflicting with:

1. Two js files are

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   ```
2. One from mockup file is:

   ```
    <script src="scripts/webedit.js"></script>
   ```

These 3 files are confilicting  when i Load the page and drag and drop is not working and showing

```
  TypeError: jQuery(...).fileReaderJS is not a function
```

JS:

```
 <script>
    jQuery("#loadFile").fileReaderJS({//fixme: can we make this class as elementgetter?
        accept: 'text/*',
        readAsDefault: 'Text',
        on:{
            load:function(e,file){
                appendJqueryToQuickmockupDom(readStringToJquery(e.target.result)); //ugly!!!
                setupElements();
            }
        }
    });
```

on that loadFile.

and this is my Editor file who can edit a text field

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/wysiwyg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/wysiwyg-editor.js"></script>
    <!-- github.io delivers wrong content-type - but you may want to include FontAwesome in 'wysiwyg-editor.css' -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/wysiwyg-editor.css" />
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Full featured editor
        $('.editor1,#editor2,#editor3').each( function(index, element)
        {
            $(element).wysiwyg({
                classes: 'some-more-classes',
                position: index == 0 ? 'top-selection' : (index == 1 ? 'bottom' : 'selection'),
                buttons: {
                    // Dummy-HTML-Plugin
                    dummybutton1: index != 1 ? false : {
                        html: $('<input id="submit" type="button" value="bold" />').click(function(){
                                    // We simply make 'bold'
                                    if( $(element).wysiwyg('selected-html') )
                                        $(element).wysiwyg('bold');
                                    else
                                        alert( 'Please selection some text' );
                                }),
                        //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                        showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                    },
                // Dummy-Button-Plugin
                dummybutton2: index != 1 ? false : {
                    title: 'Dummy',
                    image: '\uf1e7',
                    click: function( $button ) {
                            alert('Do something');
                           },
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                // Smiley-Plugin
                smilies: {
                    title: 'Smilies',
                    image: '\uf118', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    popup: function( $popup, $button, $editor ) {
                            var list_smilies = [
                                    '<img src="smiley/afraid.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/amorous.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/angel.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/angry.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/bored.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/cold.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/confused.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/cross.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/crying.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/devil.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/disappointed.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/dont-know.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/drool.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/embarrassed.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/excited.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/excruciating.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/eyeroll.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/happy.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/hot.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/hug-left.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/hug-right.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/hungry.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/invincible.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/kiss.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/lying.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/meeting.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/nerdy.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/neutral.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/party.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/pirate.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/pissed-off.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/question.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/sad.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/shame.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/shocked.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/shut-mouth.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/sick.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/silent.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/sleeping.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/sleepy.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/stressed.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/thinking.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/tongue.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/uhm-yeah.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/wink.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/working.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/bathing.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/beer.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/boy.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/camera.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/chilli.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/cigarette.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/cinema.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/coffee.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/girl.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/console.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/grumpy.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/in_love.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/internet.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/lamp.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/mobile.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/mrgreen.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/musical-note.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/music.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/phone.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/plate.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/restroom.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/rose.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/search.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/shopping.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/star.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/studying.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/suit.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/surfing.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/thunder.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/tv.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/typing.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />',
                                    '<img src="smiley/writing.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />'
                            ];
                            var $smilies = $('<div/>').addClass('wysiwyg-toolbar-smilies')
                                                      .attr('unselectable','on');
                            $.each( list_smilies, function(index,smiley){
                                if( index != 0 )
                                    $smilies.append(' ');
                                var $image = $(smiley).attr('unselectable','on');
                                // Append smiley
                                var imagehtml = ' '+$('<div/>').append($image.clone()).html()+' ';
                                $image
                                    .css({ cursor: 'pointer' })
                                    .click(function(event){
                                        $(element).wysiwyg('inserthtml',imagehtml);
                                        // do not close popup
                                        //$(element).wysiwyg('close-popup');
                                    })
                                    .appendTo( $smilies );
                            });
                            $smilies.css({ maxWidth: parseInt($editor.width()*0.95)+'px' });
                            $popup.append( $smilies );
                            // Smilies do not close on click, so force the popup-position to cover the toolbar
                            var $toolbar = $button.parents( '.wysiwyg-toolbar' );
                            if( ! $toolbar.length ) // selection toolbar?
                                return ;
                            var left = 0,
                                top = 0,
                                node = $toolbar.get(0);
                            while( node )
                            {
                                left += node.offsetLeft;
                                top += node.offsetTop;
                                node = node.offsetParent;
                            }
                            left += parseInt( ($toolbar.outerWidth() - $popup.outerWidth()) / 2 );
                            if( $toolbar.hasClass('wysiwyg-toolbar-top') )
                                top -= $popup.height() - parseInt($button.outerHeight() * 1/4);
                            else
                                top += parseInt($button.outerHeight() * 3/4);
                            $popup.css({ left: left + 'px',
                                         top: top + 'px'
                                       });
                            // prevent applying position
                            return false;
                           },
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: index == 2 ? true : false    // wanted on selection
                },
                insertimage: {
                    title: 'Insert image',
                    image: '\uf030', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                insertlink: {
                    title: 'Insert link',
                    image: '\uf08e' // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                },
                // Fontanme + Fontsize Plugin
                fontname: index == 1 ? false : {
                    title: 'Font',
                    image: '\uf031', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    popup: function( $popup, $button, $editor ) {
                            var list_fontnames = {
                                    // Name : Font
                                    'Arial, Helvetica' : 'Arial,Helvetica',
                                    'Verdana'          : 'Verdana,Geneva',
                                    'Georgia'          : 'Georgia',
                                    'Courier New'      : 'Courier New,Courier',
                                    'Times New Roman'  : 'Times New Roman,Times'
                                };
                            var $list = $('<div/>').addClass('wysiwyg-toolbar-list')
                                                   .attr('unselectable','on');
                            $.each( list_fontnames, function( name, font ){
                                var $link = $('<a/>').attr('href','#')
                                                    .css( 'font-family', font )
                                                    .html( name )
                                                    .click(function(event){
                                                        $(element).wysiwyg('fontname',font);
                                                        $(element).wysiwyg('close-popup');
                                                        // prevent link-href-#
                                                        event.stopPropagation();
                                                        event.preventDefault();
                                                        return false;
                                                    });
                                $list.append( $link );
                            });
                            $popup.append( $list );
                           },
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: index == 0 ? true : false    // wanted on selection
                },
                fontsize: index == 1 ? false : {
                    title: 'Size',
                    image: '\uf034', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    popup: function( $popup, $button, $editor ) {
                            var list_fontsizes = {
                                // Name : Size
                                'Huge'    : 7,
                                'Larger'  : 6,
                                'Large'   : 5,
                                'Normal'  : 4,
                                'Small'   : 3,
                                'Smaller' : 2,
                                'Tiny'    : 1
                            };
                            var $list = $('<div/>').addClass('wysiwyg-toolbar-list')
                                                   .attr('unselectable','on');
                            $.each( list_fontsizes, function( name, size ){
                                var $link = $('<a/>').attr('href','#')
                                                    .css( 'font-size', (8 + (size * 3)) + 'px' )
                                                    .html( name )
                                                    .click(function(event){
                                                        $(element).wysiwyg('fontsize',size);
                                                        $(element).wysiwyg('close-popup');
                                                        // prevent link-href-#
                                                        event.stopPropagation();
                                                        event.preventDefault();
                                                        return false;
                                                    });
                                $list.append( $link );
                            });
                            $popup.append( $list );
                           }
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    //showselection: true    // wanted on selection
                },
                bold: {
                    title: 'Bold (Ctrl+B)',
                    image: '\uf032', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    hotkey: 'b'
                },
                italic: {
                    title: 'Italic (Ctrl+I)',
                    image: '\uf033', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    hotkey: 'i'
                },
                underline: {
                    title: 'Underline (Ctrl+U)',
                    image: '\uf0cd', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    hotkey: 'u'
                },
                strikethrough: {
                    title: 'Strikethrough (Ctrl+S)',
                    image: '\uf0cc', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    hotkey: 's'
                },
                forecolor: {
                    title: 'Text color',
                    image: '\uf1fc' // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                },
                highlight: {
                    title: 'Background color',
                    image: '\uf043' // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                },
                alignleft: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Left',
                    image: '\uf036', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                aligncenter: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Center',
                    image: '\uf037', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                alignright: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Right',
                    image: '\uf038', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                alignjustify: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Justify',
                    image: '\uf039', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                subscript: index == 1 ? false : {
                    title: 'Subscript',
                    image: '\uf12c', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: true    // wanted on selection
                },
                superscript: index == 1 ? false : {
                    title: 'Superscript',
                    image: '\uf12b', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: true    // wanted on selection
                },
                indent: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Indent',
                    image: '\uf03c', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                outdent: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Outdent',
                    image: '\uf03b', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                orderedList: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Ordered list',
                    image: '\uf0cb', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                unorderedList: index != 0 ? false : {
                    title: 'Unordered list',
                    image: '\uf0ca', // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                    //showstatic: true,    // wanted on the toolbar
                    showselection: false    // wanted on selection
                },
                removeformat: {
                    title: 'Remove format',
                    image: '\uf12d' // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
                }
            },
            // Submit-Button
            submit: {
                title: 'Submit',
                image: '\uf00c' // <img src="path/to/image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
            },
            // Other properties
            dropfileclick: 'Drop image or click',
            placeholderUrl: 'www.example.com',
            maxImageSize: [600,200]
            /*
            onImageUpload: function( insert_image ) {
                            // Used to insert an image without XMLHttpRequest 2
                            // A bit tricky, because we can't easily upload a file
                            // via '$.ajax()' on a legacy browser.
                            // You have to submit the form into to a '<iframe/>' element.
                            // Call 'insert_image(url)' as soon as the file is online
                            // and the URL is available.
                            // Best way to do: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
                            // For example:
                            //$(this).parents('form')
                            //       .attr('action','/path/to/file')
                            //       .attr('method','POST')
                            //       .attr('enctype','multipart/form-data')
                            //       .ajaxSubmit({
                            //          success: function(xhrdata,textStatus,jqXHR){
                            //            var image_url = xhrdata;
                            //            console.log( 'URL: ' + image_url );
                            //            insert_image( image_url );
                            //          }
                            //        });
                        },
            onKeyEnter: function() {
                            return false; // swallow enter
                        }
            */
            })
            .change(function(){
                if( typeof console != 'undefined' )
                    console.log( 'change' );
            })
            .focus(function(){
                if( typeof console != 'undefined' )
                    console.log( 'focus' );
            })
            .blur(function(){
                if( typeof console != 'undefined' )
                    console.log( 'blur' );
            });
        });

        // Demo-Buttons
        $('#editor3-bold').click(function(){
            $('#editor3').wysiwyg('bold');
            return false;
        });
        $('#editor3-red').click(function(){
            $('#editor3').wysiwyg('highlight','#ff0000');
            return false;
        });
        $('#editor3-sethtml').click(function(){
            $('#editor3').wysiwyg('html', 'This is a the html text');
            return false;
        });
        $('#editor3-inserthtml').click(function(){
            $('#editor3').wysiwyg('inserthtml', 'This is some text');
            return false;
        });

    // Raw editor

    //wysiwygeditor.setHTML( '<html>' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: More information is required to answer this question. Why do you say the files are conflicting? The error seems to be saying fileReaderJS is not a function. Maybe the fileReaderJS library is not being loaded at all, or maybe you're trying to use it before it is loaded. What does a mockup file mean? Please show a file list and explain why you think this is a conflict error. As much information as you can provide. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Who wrote those // comments, did you add those? It's quite confusing to try to understand. If you really think it's a conflict between different versions of jQuery, you can fix it by using $.noConflict()

Comment: Ok sir please wait a while

Comment: So there are two html files, one is called the mockup page, and one is called the editor page, yes? What is the relationship between the two pages? When does filereaderJS work, and when does it not work, and on what pages?